# Renaming a file using a conditional statement

Tags: rename, lookup

How to rename file names using if condition?

I have many files on my computer and would like to change its names so that it would be more meaningful for me. The filenames are in the following format: cvcvcv198307.xlsx

I want to change it in such a way that

cvcvcv into Domain
1983 want to keep it
07 into 3-1 * And here is my main problem (Explanation below).

Each month (01-12) is divided into three data points. Meaning,

01(Jan) has three data points: 1,2, and 3

02(Feb) has the next three data points: 4,5, and 6

.
.
.
12(Dec) will have: 34,35, and 36

```
So, 01 in my original data means, first month, first data point, i.e. 1-1
    02 - First month, and second data point, i.e. 1-2
    03 - First month, third data point, i.e 1-3
    04- second month, first data point, i.e. 2-1
    05- 2-2
    06- 2-3
    07 - 3-1
    08 - 3-2
    09 - 3-3
    10 - 4-1
    11 - 4-2
    12 - 4-3
    .
    . 
    .
    35 - 12-2
    36 - 12-3
```

And that's all.

## I have tried file.rename along with sapply for my whole sets of data

## (1:18,000). But i can only manage to change the file names before the last two #digits.

Expected result.

The whole file names changed from

cvcvcv198307.xlsx
cvcvcv198414.xlsx
into
Domain1983-3-1.txt
Domain1984-5-2.txt

## (Yes, file name extension too!)

Comment: What context is this exactly? Programming language/shell ?

Comment: Got a solution in either case?